# Error de sintaxis en diferentes versiones de python en la libreria struct pack

Tags: python, struct

Cuando realizo el comando `struct.pack("I", 0x7ffff7e11410)` de la librería `struct` en python 2.6 la operación es realizada sin problemas. Sin embargo cuando realizo la misma operación en python 2.7 o python 3.0 me sale un error que pongo a continuación:

```
struct.error: 'I' format requires 0 <= number <= 4294967295
```

Quisiera saber si hay un cambio de sintaxis entre esas versiones que me ayude a realizar esta operación. Cualquier ayuda será muy apreciada.
Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Realmente el mensaje de error que te está dando Python 2.7 y superior es correcto. El número que intentas empaquetar no cabe en un "long". Se ve que Python 2.6 no verificaba si cabía o no.

El formato `l` significa "long", que es un dato de 32 bits. En hexadecimal eso sería como máximo el `0xffffffff`, es decir, ocho cifras hexadecimales. Tu número tiene más (tiene 12 cifras hex), por lo que no cabría en un dato de tipo "long" y tendrías que ir a uno de tipo "long long", en el que caben hasta 64 bits (16 cifras hexadecimales).

El especificador para "long long" es `q`, por tanto lo siguiente ya no dará error:

```
struct.pack("q",  0x7ffff7e11410)
```

El problema es que el resultado tendrá 8 bytes y no 4 como aparentemente querrías (pues para eso estabas especificando `"l"`). Es decir, el resultado de esta operación no es compatible con el resultado que te daba en Python 2.6

Pero ya que de todas formas es imposible meter ese número en 4 bytes, yo asumo que lo que hacía Python 2.6 era eliminar "silenciosamente" los que no cabían, quedándose sólo con los 4 inferiores. Por tanto en el fondo hacía lo mismo que:

```
struct.pack("l", 0xf7e11410)
```

Esta instrucción también sería válida en python 2.7 y superior y no te dará error.

Cuál de las dos que te he mostrado es la correcta en tu caso sólo lo sabes tú. ¿Necesitas que el resultado tenga solo 4 bytes? Entonces usa la segunda, pero el número que estarías guardando no sería el que crees. ¿Necesitas que el número sea ese? Usa entonces la primera, pero entonces ocupará 8 bytes y no 4.